# START TRANSACTION and COMMIT not working in separate queries in MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, transactions, commit

When I send a multiple line semicolon separated query (i.e. 3 separate queries), it works fine, depending on whether I finish it with a `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`, it either inserts the values or rolls back. BUT when I enter them in three separate queries, one after another, now that's not gonna work. (I'm using PHP MyAdmin)

The latter would have to make more sense, as I think this the whole point in transactions, to send queries in a session (transaction) and deciding only at the end whether we want to run them or discard changes to the table.

`START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO x VALUES ('y');
COMMIT;`

Comment: Can you show us your PHP code?  This should work if done directly from MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

phpMyAdmin doesn't work that way: It doesn't maintain the session between each submission of the form, so you wont get the desired functionality you're looking for that way.

In code, on the other hand, this will work as intended because you're opening up the connection once, running 3 individual queries, and then closing the connection.

Comment: Thank you so much, so PHP MyAdmin was the source of the problem, just tried it through my program and it worked fine.